# C# SQL SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (clause from Table1) AND (clause from Table2)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two tables **SupplierTable** and **Calendar**, both have a column called **SupplierName**. I have an asp calendar function on a page called **SuppplierDetails.aspx**.

All details on this page are called from a db connection to the **SupplierTable** and displayed in labels. I need my calendar function to highlight dates from the **CalendarTable** where the **SupplierName** is equal to the **SupplierName** name on the current page (equal to the current label).

My query:

```
"SELECT Date FROM Calendar WHERE SupplierName= "+ 
Request.QueryString["SupplierName"] + "AND Date = @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate";
```

firstDate is the first date of the current month and lastDate is the last date of the current month.
I then use the DayRender method to turn the pages red.

Currently this is giving me an error, I know the issue is in the WHERE part of the query but cannot find the write code to correct it. If I remove the the SupplilerName from the WHERE clause it works - it just displays all dates in all calendars. I need it to only show the dates for the current supplier.
Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: What is the string output of the query when you inspect it before it runs? I am guessing your date format is incorrect and not properly wrapped as strings.

Comment: I don't know what the error says but you might miss the quotes within the suppliername

Comment: You need quotes around supplier name if it is string and a space before "AND" condition after suppliername: "SELECT Date FROM Calendar WHERE SupplierName= '"+ Request.QueryString["SupplierName"] + "' AND Date = @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate";

Comment: first of all, this has a classic sql injection security issue , concatenation of Request.querystring and the sql query is  bad practice

Comment: Most probably `SupplierName` is of character type in DB , so you need quotes.

Comment: If it's not a copy/paste error, currently your supplier name is next to `AND` clause. Unless it has a blank space at the end, you should add a blank space before `AND`.And really, REALLY, never use concatenation for sql querys. I don't know why you use parameters for dates and not for SupplierName

Comment: It breaks and returns Stack empty.

Comment: Thanks Zaki, I tried your suggestion above. I no longer get the Stack empty error but the calendar does not display any dates. I have parameters on the dates, but was unsure of what way to put them for supplier name: 
oCMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstDate", firstDate));
oCMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastDate", lastDate));

Answer (score 1):

[Using parameters](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) should solve the issue. Simply make your query:

```
"SELECT Date FROM Calendar WHERE SupplierName= @SupplierName AND Date = @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate";
```

You can add your supplier name parameter using:

```
oCMD.Parameters.Add("@SupplierName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Request.QueryString["SupplierName"];
```

It is also not a good idea to [use `SELECT *` in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: Thanks so much for the above, I have updated my code to reflect. 
However, I still don't get the desired outcome and think it could be an issue with how I have declared daysBooked and now when I run the code it breaks and takes me back to daysBooked with an error saying cannot find table 0. I have updated my original question to reflect this

Comment: You would need to post the code for the method `GetCurrentMonthData()` in order for me to be able to answer that.

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT Date FROM Calendar WHERE SupplierName= "+ 
Request.QueryString["SupplierName"] + "AND Date = @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate";
```

if your supplier name is let's say "George", you will end up with this query :

```
"SELECT Date FROM Calendar WHERE SupplierName= GeorgeAND Date = xx/xx/xx AND Date < yy/yy/yyy";
```

As you can see, you just need a space before your AND, otherwise it will be interpreted as one word.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, when I entered the above I didn't get any errors but my calendar displayed no dates. 
This could be because of the DayRender method:

Answer (score -1):

I think this would solve your problem

```
"SELECT Date FROM Calendar WHERE SupplierName= '"+ 
    Request.QueryString["SupplierName"] + "' AND Date = @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate";
```

You should use `debug mode` to view your query to see the single quote `'` missing

Comment: Thanks for the above, I have updated my code to reflect. However, I still don't get the desired outcome and think it could be an issue with how I have declared daysBooked and now when I run the code it breaks and takes me back to daysBooked with an error saying **cannot find table 0**. I have updated my original question to reflect this

Answer (score -2):

First You need to join both table by using join operation :

correct query is :SELECT Date FROM Calendar,SupplierTable  WHERE SupplierName= "+ Request.QueryString["SupplierName"] + "AND Date = @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate

Comment: Thanks Pushpendra, I tried the above but got an error saying Stack empty